# Write specific parts from string into another string

Tags: python, ping, icmp

I'm currently writing a script to monitor hosts via a python script and ping. The ouput of ping is saved into the variable response which is perfectly working. The content of response variable looks like this:

[image]

Now I would like to save the marked values into the variables min, avg and max, but I have no idea how to do this?

Comment: it would be helpful for those looking at your question to see an embedded image (rather than a link). Better yet you could include the text log text so that it can be searched for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can process the string like this:

- split it by lines `x = response.splitlines()`
- get the last line `x = x[-1]`
- get the substring that contains the values `x = x.split(" = ")[1]`
- get the individual min, max, avg values `min, avg, max = x.split("/")[:3]` (this way they will be stored as strings)
- to save them as numbers, you can do this instead: `min, avg, max = map(float, x.split("/")[:3])`